# SDL Tridion SP 1 HR 1 - Upgrading default template building blocks

Tags: tridion

I'm trying to install the new UI functionality on an upgraded SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR 1 machine and have ran into a small issue.

When opening the template builder to upgrade the default building blocks using 'tools > create default building blocks' (as described here: [sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=InstallingServerRolesInDotNET.xml](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=InstallingServerRolesInDotNET.xml)) the process completes, but I don't get the latest building blocks, for example 'Enable Inline Editing For Content' isn't installed on the CMS.

My question is, how manually do I upgrade this to ensure my default TBB files are correct?   I'm guessing I drop the correct dll somewhere and then again ask the template builder to perform the creation of the default building blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SOLVED] I found the **Tridion.SiteEdit.Templating dll** on another SDL Tridion machine and saw it contained the two building blocks that seem to be missing.

On this environment I've manually added the dll and then manually created the two template building blocks + the two parameters schemas that are required.   Not the fastest way to do it, but it all works splendidly !

If there is a neater way to resolve this please add to this :)

Comment: Tridion.SiteEdit.Templating dll is not part of the "Default Building Blocks", so it's no wonder Template Builder didn't create them... unless you're using Tridion UI 2012, in which case running the UI installer would have added this DLL to your "Defaults". Maybe you didn't run the installer?

Comment: yeah I did, but you know me and installing things :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always found Tridion.SiteEdit.Templating dll on Tridion bin folder after UI installation.